# What's the purpose of the Golem at the Cliffside Airdock in Bryyo?

Tags: metroid-prime-3-corruption

In *Metroid Prime 3: Corruption*, if you land on Bryyo at the Cliffside Airdock, there's a large room with grapple hooks along the top, and a disabled Mogenar War Golem. I think the room is called the "Grand Court"? I got the X-Ray visor and managed to restore power to the Golem which stood up to reveal a pool of Phazon. But that was all!

Am I missing something? I've been longing to activate this Golem since I first found it early in the game, expecting some amazing prize. Where's my energy tank‽

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you destroyed the Leviathan Seed on Bryyo yet? According to [this](http://metroid.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Court) the only item in the room is a Red Phazoid (which only begin to appear after you've destroyed the appropriate Seed) and it's associated gold credit.

Comment: Ok, that's right, I did kill a Red Phazoid and got a gold credit... but that's all that's there! How lame! :-(